# Can I code-sign an App for a Client to App store with my own keys?

Tags: iphone

I'm developping an app for a client. 
Must the finial ipa be code signed with the private key and certificate of the client?
What happens when i code sign the app with my own key and certificate and then submit it in the itunes account of my client?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Not sure whether an exact duplicate, but you can check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951874/apple-appstore-and-developers-identification-policy/5952141#5952141